# What does it mean by "Events with the same name must have the same parameters"?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Classes/Analytics#/c:objc(cs)FIRAnalytics(cm)logEventWithName:parameters:

Under logEvent(_:parameters:), it says:
Events with the same name must have the same parameters.

What does this mean?

I am asking because in my app, I fire several events with same name but different parameters. How is this going to affect my data?